# How do I know when to abandon vendor specific prefixes?

Tags: javascript

I am using IndexedDB feature of the browsers.  And up to now I've using this line to check if the browsers support it:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB 
              || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

if (window.indexedDB) { ... }
```

At this point, most vendors have implemented the feature.  At what point is it safe to abandon all the vendor specific prefixes and just straight out check for window.indexedDB?  Is there a site like caniuse.com or something like that?

Comment: nowdays browser vendors are creating status websites, listing the status for each feature, for example: https://www.chromestatus.com or https://status.modern.ie/

Comment: Note that although a question about CSS, the same applies in my answer for that question as it would for this. Here is the Can I Use page for `indexedDB`: http://caniuse.com/#search=IndexedDB.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=indexedDb

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Right, I saw that page.  I am just not sure how to read it.  Where specifically does it state that I can remove the prefix?  Does "Supported" or "Partially Supported" signify that?